# Change filter order of values based on parameter

Tags: tableau-api

​Hi all,

I am trying to change the order of the values in the filter based on a parameter I've chosen. For example if I choose "Calendar" in the parameter, I'd want my filter values to start from January, February, March... until December. If I choose "Financial" in my parameter, I'd want it to start from July, August, September... Til June as the last month.

How can I implement this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would create additional calculated fields that represent the numerical order of my months. For example, "calendar" would give January a value of 1, Feb 2, and so on. In a similar manner, "financial" would give July 1, Sept 2, etc.

From there, you can make a parameter control that dictates the sort that you should use. This is a great tutorial on doing that. 
[Create Parameter control for sort in Tableau](http://kb.tableau.com/articles/knowledgebase/sort-using-parameter-control)

The generated sort fields that are created to dictate the sort order should not have to be shown on your final viz.